# Good way to implement an alarm clock

Tags: c++

this may be very conceptual, but I am entirely out of ideas on this subject. FYI I am coding this in Arduino (C/C++).

I was wondering what the best way to implement an alarm trigger would be.

The way I have it now is I convert the time into seconds and convert the alarm time into seconds. When the current time is greater or equal to the alarm time, the alarm triggers.

This works fine. Imagine I set the current time as 1 am (3600 seconds) and the alarm time at 2 am (7200 seconds). When the total seconds equal 7200, the alarm will trigger.

However, my issue is that if the current time is set before midnight and the alarm time after midnight, the alarm will trigger right away.

Indeed, imagine I set the current time at 10pm (approx 70000 seconds) and the alarm time at 00:00:01 (1 second). The current time will be greater then the alarm time and will trigger instantaneously.

Any ideas on how I could work around this would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Asking for _"Any ideas?"_ sounds too broad to be asked here. This may turn into an endless discussion which is what we don't want here. The site is rather about concise FAQ like question and answer pairs. You also may want to read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Just a suggestion, can you use std::time_t ?

Comment: Why not add the total seconds of the current date and time to all times and add an additional 86400 seconds to the alarm time when the it is set for a time of day greater than the current time of day.

Comment: I have tried playing around with the idea of the days incrementing when past midnight. But i cant think of a way to implement that because as soon as the alarm time is set (if it is after midnight and the current time before), the condition checking if it is smaller triggers. I tried adding an and statement that checks if the day (day 5) is the same or if it has increased (6) but this doesn't work because the day of the current time is always set to 5 and I cannot ask the user what datehe would like the alarm to ring.

Answer (score 0):

As you set the problem, you shouldn't check if one value is bigger than the other, but if the running time crossed the alarm.
So suppose the alarm is at point a.
Time was t_old and now it is t.
What we have to check is if a is between t_old and t.
That seems easy to say, but a little bit more difficult to do.

Any way, subtracting from all values t_old, we have t_old=0 a-t_old and t-t_old. So using usigned arithmetic if a-t_old is < t-t_old it is your case ( check it and if I did any error inform me).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, howecer I dont think this will work. Assume I set the current time at 18pm (t_old). It is now 20pm (t). The alarm is set for 15pm(a). Using the formula, 15-18 < 20-18 is true. However this should not happen. Indeed, the alarm needs to way 19 hours until it reaches 15pm, but yet, the condition is triggered

Comment: Every time you check the alarm you set t_old=t and t=now . So suppose you check for alarm conditions every 5 minutes, then last time you checked was 19:55pm and now is 20:00pm the alarm is set at 15pm. We use integer unsigned arithmetic and we subtract from 20:00pm 19:55pm and from 15:00pm 19:55pm ( you should have converted time to seconds before hand ). The result is that 20:00pm becomes 00:05 and 15:00pm given the unsigned arithmetic becomes (24:00+15:00-19:55=20:55). So now we have that 20:55 isn't smaller (or equal) than 00:05 so the alarm hasn't been triggered as it should be.